# Unexpected tASSOC while .push in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

when I enter the next line in code editor I received an `Unexpected tASSOC error`. As far as I understand this is because I'm using the `=>` operator.

```
@inserts.push("'#{:userid=>userid}', '#{:name=>name}'")
```

What I want is that `@inserts` in the position `[x]` contains for example `'001' , 'name'`

Comment: Which output do you expect from that line? This is definitely not ruby syntax.

Comment: puts @inserts[x]     output= '001' , 'name'

Comment: Which local variables do you have in your context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are misusing symbols and hash notation. Try the line instead:

```
@inserts.push("'#{userid}', '#{name}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid Ruby and the parser is giving you an error. What you probably mean is:

```
@inserts.push(:userid => userid, :name => name)
```